# How to Prevent Scrolling within FrameLayouts and Instead Have the Parent LinearLayout Handle all Scrolling?

Tags: android, scroll, height, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have a scrollable LinearLayout parent with a few FrameLayouts nested inside it as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/hb_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/gn_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/yt_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like FrameLayouts to take up the space they need, allowing for scrolling of the full view through the LinearLayout.

Issue is: the LinearLayout will only take up the screen, it won't scroll, instead the FrameLayout's will scroll if the content overflows the bottom of the screen.

To be clear, I just want the FrameLayouts to fill whatever space they need, and the LinearLayout can scroll it like one long view. Must I fix the FrameLayout heights to achieve this? If so, is there risk of my layout breaking on different screen sizes/densities (or does DP really work in all cases?).

Thank you immensely!

EDIT: I have confirmed that setting fixed heights in the FrameLayout does exactly what I want this to do: scroll as one. However, why doesn't wrap_content measure the height and then go from there? That is what I expected the case was... I'm not certain how to judge the right heights for each element.

Comment: 8 years after, I encountered the same. I think you are correct about the reasonable behavior that should occur. Looks like a bug to me. The workaround of setting the size works, but it will probably be a problem when the content indeed will not fit (on different screen size or dynamic content).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a scrollview to the layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/hb_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/gn_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/yt_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately no, the behaviour is the same as the ScrollView acts just like the parent LinearLayout in my example above.

I am trying to model this off of what the Google Play store does in the home screen. I'm certain they must be using fragments for those different boxes... But the whole view scrolls.